# Easy way to compare mysql entries in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my database I have entries like:

```
username score     date
User1      10    1/1/2013
User2       4    1/1/2013
User3       4    1/1/2013
User4       5    1/1/2013

...

User1       1    10/1/2013
User2       3    10/1/2013
User3       4    10/1/2013
User4      17    10/1/2013
```

And I need to find wich users score is changed most. It is not so easy because there is around 30k users. So I thought there is more elegent way than query them all and do the math

**UPD:** Also the date is stored in datetime format and I do not know exact time when score was stored...

Comment: Changed the most from first entry to last entry? Or recent entry to last entry?

Answer (score 0):

If by "changed the most", you mean "changed the greatest number of times", then the SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(*) as times_changed FROM table_name GROUP BY username ORDER BY times_changed DESC LIMIT 1;
```

You can run that with:

```
 result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

If the table is large, it would be better to cache the "number of times changed" in each User record.

If you mean "changed by the greatest numeric amount between 2 given dates", then the SQL would look like:

```
SELECT t1.username, ABS(t1.score - t2.score) AS difference FROM table_name AS t1 JOIN table_name AS t2 WHERE t1.username = t2.username AND t1.date = 'date here' AND t2.date = 'other date here';
```

Comment: The second is what I need ("changed by the greatest numeric amount between 2 given dates"). But I've got an error when query it. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Column 'user' in field list is ambiguous:`

Comment: Alex, could you please change it to use not the exact dates, but the range of dates, beacouse there can be several entries for one user for one date. Best case scenario is that the SQL will take the latest entry for a given date. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing, to get user who has maximum score difference in that table layout :

```
Select username, max(score) 
from (
    select C1.username, abs(C1.score - C2.score) score from table_name C1, table_name C2 
    where C1.username = C2.username and C1.score <> C2.score
) as T;
```

Comment: I've got an error `Error: Unknown column 'score' in 'field list':` Also in my table the score is stored each day but I want to compare todays score with score from week ago.